# Figure out transaction id after submitting using cardano cli

Tags: cardano-cli

It's possible to submit transactions using cardano cli. Here is an example (assumes you have gone through the steps to build the tx):

```
cardano-cli transaction submit --tx-file matx.signed --mainnet
```

I would like to follow up on the transaction after submitting. For that I need the transaction ID. Is there a way to derive or otherwise programatically figure out the transaction Id of a tx created in this manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the above example, you would run:

`cardano-cli transaction txid --tx-file matx.signed`

If instead of inspecting a signed transaction you wish to inspect a transaction body / unsigned draft, it would look similar:

`cardano-cli transaction txid --tx-body-file tx.draft`

The Txid will be printed to `stdout`